# XML data file not opening and working properly

Tags: c#, wpf, xml

I developed a WPF application using XML as the database file. Yesterday, the program stopped working. After some checking, I saw that there was a problem with **Transaction.xml** file. I tried opening the same in IE, but got this error

> The XML page cannot be displayed
>
> Cannot view XML input using style sheet. Please correct the error and then click the Refresh button, or try again later.
>
> ---
>
> An invalid character was found in text content. Error processing resource 'file:///C:/RegisterMaintenance/Transaction.xml

Then, I tried opening the file in notepad and it showed weird character(screenshot below).

[image]

In the end, its displaying the right structure of xml. Please tell me what has gone wrong and why the xml not showing correctly. How can get it to normal state. I am really worried as this is my only data file. Any help or suggestion will be great.

One of the codes that edit this file, there are other similar types of code files that use **Transaction.xml**

```
public string Add()
    {
        XDocument doc1 = XDocument.Load(@"Ledgers.xml");
        XElement elem = (from r in doc1.Descendants("Ledger")
                where r.Element("Name").Value == this.Buyer
                select r).First();
        this.TinNo = (string)elem.Element("TinNo");
        this.PhoneNo = (string)elem.Element("PhoneNo");
        this.CommissionAmount = (this.CommissionRate * this.Amount) / 100;
        this.CommissionAmount = Math.Round((decimal)this.CommissionAmount);
        this.VatAmount = (this.CommissionAmount + this.Amount) * this.VatRate / 100;
        this.VatAmount = Math.Round((decimal)this.VatAmount);
        this.InvoiceAmount = this.Amount + this.CommissionAmount + this.VatAmount;
        XDocument doc2 = XDocument.Load(@"Transactions.xml");
        var record = from r in doc2.Descendants("Transaction")
                     where (int)r.Element("Serial") == Serial
                     select r;
        foreach (XElement r in record)
        {
            r.Element("Invoice").Add(new XElement("InvoiceNo", this.InvoiceNo), new XElement("InvoiceDate", this.InvoiceDate),
                new XElement("TinNo", this.TinNo), new XElement("PhoneNo", this.PhoneNo), new XElement("TruckNo", this.TruckNo), new XElement("Source", this.Source),
                new XElement("Destination", this.Destination), new XElement("InvoiceAmount", this.InvoiceAmount),
                new XElement("CommissionRate", this.CommissionRate), new XElement("CommissionAmount", this.CommissionAmount),
                new XElement("VatRate", this.VatRate), new XElement("VatAmount", this.VatAmount));
        }
        doc2.Save(@"Transactions.xml");
        return "Invoice Created Successfully";
    }
```

Comment: It was `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> `

Comment: Is there any editor that opens this file so that there are no weird characters (maybe UltraEdit)?

Comment: @Ivan__83 I downloaded the ultraedit and opened the file with it. Its displaying in the same manner :-(

Comment: Is it safe to assume that your data is not normally a bunch of device and package names? I wouldn't be surprised if this had nothing to do with your application and something got messed up with your local drive. Run a chkdsk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**C#** is an **Object Orient Programming** (OOP) language, perhaps you should use some objects!  How can you possibly test your code for accuracy?

You should separate out responsibilities, an example:

```
public class Vat
{
    XElement self;
    public Vat(XElement parent)
    {
        self = parent.Element("Vat");
        if (null == self)
        {
            parent.Add(self = new XElement("Vat"));
            // Initialize values
            Amount = 0; 
            Rate = 0;
        }
    }

    public XElement Element { get { return self; } }

    public decimal Amount
    {
        get { return (decimal)self.Attribute("Amount"); }
        set
        {
            XAttribute a = self.Attribute("Amount");
            if (null == a)
                self.Add(new XAttribute("Amount", value));
            else
                a.Value = value.ToString();
        }
    }

    public decimal Rate
    {
        get { return (decimal)self.Attribute("Rate"); }
        set
        {
            XAttribute a = self.Attribute("Rate");
            if (null == a)
                self.Add(new XAttribute("Rate", value));
            else
                a.Value = value.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

All the Vat data will be in one node, and all the accessing of it will be in one testable class.

Your above foreach would look more like:

```
foreach(XElement r in record)
{
    XElement invoice = r.Add("Invoice");
    ...
    Vat vat = new Vat(invoice);
    vat.Amount = this.VatAmount;
    vat.Rate = this.VatRate;
}
```

That is readable!  At a glance, from your code, I cannot even tell if invoice is the parent of Vat, but I can now!

**Note:** This isn't to say your code is at fault, it could be a hard-drive error, as that is what it looks like to me.  But if you want people to peruse your code, make it readable and testable!  Years from now if you or someone else has to change your code, if it isn't readable, it is useless.

Perhaps from this incident you learned two things

1. read-ability and test-ability.
2. Backups!  (All my valuable Xml files are in a SVN (TortoiseSVN) so I can compare what has changed, as well as keeping good backups.  The SVN is backed-up to online storage.)

An ideal next step is to take the code in the property setters and refactor that out to a static function extension that is both testable and reproducable:

```
public static class XAttributeExtensions
{
    public static XAttribute SetAttribute(this XElement self, string name, object value)
    {
        // test for correct arguments
        if (null == self)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("XElement to SetAttribute method cannot be null!");
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(name))
            throw new ArgumentNullException("Attribute name cannot be null or empty to SetAttribute method!");
        if (null == value) // how to handle?
            value = ""; // or can throw an exception like one of the above.

        // Now to the good stuff
        XAttribute a = self.Attribute(name);
        if (null == a)
            self.Add(a = new XAttribute(name, value));
        else
            a.Value = value.ToString();
        return a;
    }
}
```

That is easily testable, very readable and the best is it can be used over and over again getting the same results!

Example, the Amount property can be greatly simplified with:

```
public decimal Amount
{
    get { return (decimal)self.Attribute("Amount"); }
    set { self.SetAttribute("Amount", value); }
}
```

I know this is a lot of boiler-plate code, but I find it readable, extendable and best of all test-able.  If I want to add another value to Vat, I can just modify the class and not have to worry about have I added it in the right place.  If Vat had children, I'd make another class that Vat had a property for.

Answer (score 1):

The .xml is clearly malformed. No browser or other program that reads xml files will be able to do anything with it. It doesn't matter that the xml starts being correct after some lines.

So the error is most certainly it whatever creates and/or edits your xml file. You should have a look there. Maybe the encoding is wrong. The most used encoding is UTF-8.

Also, as a side note, XML is not really the best format for large databases (too much overhead), so switching to a binary format would be best. Even switching to JSON would bring a benefit.

Comment: it is `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>` . What can be done now ?? Can i recover it to normal state

Comment: No I don#t mean the xml statement that is of the bginning of an xml file (which is btw pretty optional). I mean the program that writes or edits the xml in the first place probably produces this messed up xml beginning.

Comment: I file is read and written by the WPF application i developed. The backend language is c#

Comment: Then it would maybe be a good idea to show the code in the application that is responsible for xml writing. Or not all of it, if it is too big ;)

Comment: I have edited the question with one of the codes that edits this file. There are other files too that reads and edit this file. I have shown one of the codes